# Force stop query execution in vb6

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have a report-generating module that eats quite some time when loading (perhaps due to the plethora of stored function it calls). *If only I were better at optimization. Ugh!*

Anyways, i was just wondering if there is any means to halt a (running) query in vb6?
I mean like programmatically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ADO you can move to async calls and then most objects have a Cancel method you can use.

[Cancel Method (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681014(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I think this one would suffice.